# Facebook - I can't get into my application's profile

Tags: facebook

I created new FB application to use it as a tab, but after I created it, I can't get into its profile page: https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=205809329503822, I see there only message "The page you requested was not found.". Why? Is it possible to add an application as a tab to my facebook page in other ways??

Answer (score 0):

@user971011:You might have deleted the application.Check whether your app is listed here developer.facebook.com.

If it is n't there then,you've to create a new application.